# Python Selenium Capturar fechamento indevido do browser durante teste

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, exceção

Estou fazendo uma manipulação longa do sistema pelo browser e quero registrar um log em banco de dados caso o usuário feche o browser no meio do processo.

Já tentei utilizar um try exception capturando erros do selenium porém não consegui definir qual evento devo capturar:

```
            try:
                processa_pedido(driver, pedido[0], usuario)
                sleep(1.5)
            except WebDriverException as error:
                print("Problema com o navegador!\n" + error.__str__())
                incrementa_numero_de_execucoes(pedido.NU_PEDIDO)
            except UnknownMethodException as error:
                print("Problema com o navegador!\n" + error.__str__())
                incrementa_numero_de_execucoes(pedido.NU_PEDIDO)
            except NoSuchWindowException as error:
                print("Problema com o navegador!\n" + error.__str__())
                incrementa_numero_de_execucoes(pedido.NU_PEDIDO)
```

Alguém sabe como capturo esse encerramento do browser pelo webdriver?

Comment: Procure por **ConnectionClosedException** nesta [lista de exceções do Selenium](https://www.guru99.com/exception-handling-selenium.html).

Comment: Aparentemente na versão que estou usando não encontrei essa exceção.
`from selenium.common.exceptions import ConnectionClosedException` a importação da erro.